# jQuery - how to remove a class from an element with a given delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

When a user updates a record in the database, I'll modify the record  using an AJAX request. Then, I add to the rendered `div` a class by calling the `addClass` method. The class I add (let's call the class `colored`) to the `div` contains only a `background color` directive (to highlight the current modified record).

So far so good.

Now I want to remove this class with a `fadeOut` effect, after 1 second.

I've tried these approaches, but in both cases it's not only removing the class but the whole `div`.

```
$("#id1").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('colored');
});
```

or

```
$("#id1").delay(1000).fadeOut().removeClass('updated_item');
```

Why is the `div` removed instead of the `class` ? Actually, the `div` is getting a `display: none;` style - I see this in the console.

Comment: That removed the whole div?  From the DOM? It shouldn't.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs yes, it does.

Comment: If you are trying to keep the element but hide it, you can use `fadeTo` instead.

Comment: Um, Fade Out hides the element. If you want to only change the background color, than you want to look at animate.

Comment: css is just fine for effects don't use animate for such simple tasks...

Comment: Umm... I think you are misunderstanding what the DOM is.  `.removeClass()` and `.fadeOut` will not "remove" the element.  `.fadeOut()` will stop the element from being *rendered*, but it's still alive and well in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fadeOut` will fade the entire element out and hide it from the screen.  If you want to fade the effects of the class, you can use [jQuery UI .removeClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/) (which accepts a time duration and fade effect, unlike regular jQuery) or [CSS3 transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/).

Comment: `fadeOut` does not hide the element from the DOM, it just doesn't render it.  To remove it from the DOM, you would need to `.remove()` it.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyHolovacs, that's really what I meant - hides it from the screen*  Glad it worked out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout function like this:

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        $("#id1").removeClass('updated_item');      
    }
    ,1000 //1 second
)
```

And if you want to change the color with animation you can just add a transition style in your CSS like this:

```
.myDiv{
    background:red;
    transition:background 1s;
    -webkit-transition:background 1s;
}
.colored
{
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the `fadeOut` function to the `div` itself, not on the class:

```
//the div, will fadeout after 1000 ms and get the class removed
$("#id1").delay(1000).fadeOut().removeClass('updated_item');
```

If you want to remove the `background-color` with a fading effect, you'd have to use something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#id1').removeClass('updated_item');
}, 1000)
```

On the css side, use a `transition` for the `fadeOut` effect:

```
#id1 {
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.updated_item {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qw8v4kh/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I got it, is this what you want ?
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbxo060x/)

```js
jQuery('.action').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
    if ( confirm('Are you sure?') ) {
        jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass('remove').removeClass('highlight');
        });
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    #1 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="action">Click me</a>
</div>
<div>
    #2 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="action">Click me</a>
</div>
```